# can't edit tag wiki

Tags: support, tags

I've edited a couple of tag wikis a couple of days back, this morning just had them approved which is great.  Now I go onto another tag to add some info such as the `adobe` tag which has no info.

[image]

I click on the tag and I'm invited to help create the usage guidance as there is no info for this:

[image]

But when I click on the `help us create it` link, I end up here:

[image]

and I can't see any option to edit or add wiki information.  I'm a logged in user, I've suggested an edit to other tags a couple of days ago on this same browser (and I've tried a different browser in case it's a cache issue).  Why can't I suggest an edit to this wiki?  I've gone back through and most tags show up like this, there's just a few seemingly random ones I can suggest an edit for.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this may have been due to other pending changes on the wiki that may have been blocking additional changes.  I'm not sure if it is specifically from your changes in the queue or just the number of changes on the tag.

That said, I had to reject a number of your tag alterations as they appear to be verbatim copies of Wikipedia articles on the companies or topics in question and are not suited for tag information.

Comment: Yep, I was testing what I could and couldn't edit so I copied a couple of chunks from wiki rather than using placeholder text.  Is there any guidance on adding tag information?  Just been searching and can't find anything.

Comment: @SDiraptor - honestly, I'm not sure.  There might be something over on meta.stackexchange.com that gives more guidance, but in general the idea should be to have a description that is focused on the tag usage and what the tag is for more than a detailed description of the product the tag is related to (for a product tag for example).  The reason for the tag information is to help people choose the correct tags for a question and to help define when a tag does or doesn't apply.

Comment: I did a quick look, and from the right hand panel info on the tag edit page, they had a link to this blog post with a lot more detail. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/?_ga=2.110733061.1445137593.1628103239-1334578170.1605630658